# Multiple class instances collision detection problem

Tags: c++, class, user-interface, collision-detection

To keep it short, I have this class `Display_Frame`. Within this `Display_Frame`, there are 2 rectangles. The first being its own rectangle, and the second being its internal rectangle. The first rectangle is for its positioning and dimensions on a screen, and the second (internal rectangle) is for information within that first rectangle. If the internal rectangle is bigger than the first rectangle, I initiate a scrollbar on the side to scroll for the information. This is where my problem is discovered. If I use this approach for every object on my screen, ie, the main display is its own `Display_Frame`, then any other object on the screen can also fit within another `Display_Frame` but is fitted in the screen via the main screens one. When I then scroll, How can I make sure that only the farthest branch of `Display_Frame`'s is scrolled, and not any others.

---

For example, lets say I have a textbox that fits inside its own `Display_Frame`. Its own `Display_Frame` is also embedded within the main screens `Display_Frame` too. Now lets say I want to scroll in the textbox but only if the mouse is within it. That's easy enough to detect, however how can I make it so that when I do scroll inside the textbox, the main screens `Display_Frame` doesn't scroll, only the textbox's `Display_Frame` 's internal rect is moved instead.

---

In general terms for this, how can I efficiently detect and restrict my `Display_Frame`'s to only scroll if I have scrolled on the farthest down branch of `Display_Frame`'s?

Here is some code displaying my issue:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>



class Display_Frame
{
public:
    SDL_Rect m_Display_Frame_Rect;
    SDL_Rect m_Internal_Rect;

    void Handle_Events(SDL_Point mousePos, bool scrolledDown, bool scrolledUp);

};


void Display_Frame::Handle_Events(SDL_Point mousePos, bool scrolledDown, bool scrolledUp)
{
    if (SDL_PointInRect(&mousePos, &m_Display_Frame_Rect))
    {
        if (scrolledDown){
            m_Display_Frame_Rect.y += 20;
        }
        if (scrolledUp){
            m_Display_Frame_Rect.y -= 20;
        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Rect display = {0,0,1278,718};

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0, 30, display.w+2, display.h+2, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL  | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE );
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED  );

    SDL_Rect testRect = {100, 100, 100, 100};
    SDL_Point mousePos = {0,0};
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;
    bool scrolledUp = false, scrolledDown = false;

    Display_Frame mainDisplay;
    mainDisplay.m_Display_Frame_Rect = display;
    mainDisplay.m_Internal_Rect = display;

    Display_Frame smallDisplay;
    smallDisplay.m_Display_Frame_Rect = testRect;
    smallDisplay.m_Internal_Rect = testRect;



    while (running)
    {

        scrolledDown = false;
        scrolledUp = false;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
                break;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                mousePos = {event.motion.x, event.motion.y};
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEWHEEL){

                if (event.wheel.y > 0){  ///Scrolling up here
                    scrolledUp = true;
                }
                if (event.wheel.y < 0){  ///Scrolling down here
                    scrolledDown = true;
                }
            }

        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);


        mainDisplay.Handle_Events(mousePos, scrolledDown, scrolledUp);
        smallDisplay.Handle_Events(mousePos, scrolledDown, scrolledUp);


        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0,0,0,255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &mainDisplay.m_Display_Frame_Rect);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &smallDisplay.m_Display_Frame_Rect);


        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }





    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. Simplify your issue to some small piece of code we can read and understand.

Comment: Using SDL2, the concept still applies, its just rectangles

Comment: @Jeffrey I re-edited it

Comment: I want it so when I scroll on my Main, it also scrolls on any other objects, but when I scroll on any other objects it does't scroll on my main